# Jquery Datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

Buenas noches, estoy trabajando con **Jquery**, extrayendo datos de una base de datos y creando una tabla dinámica con los datos. Es decir, realizo una extracción de datos en una funcion javascript:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", $urlEnvio, false);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("accept" ,"application/json");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("content-type" ,"application/json");
xmlhttp.send($urlEnvio);


var resultado = xmlhttp.response;
var long = resultado.length;
var elementos =JSON.parse(resultado);
```

A continuación, creo un encabezado de la tabla (es la misma del ejemplo de dataTables):

```
$('#infoDonantes').append("<div class='panel-body'>"+
    "<table width='100%' class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover' id='dataTables-example'>"+
      "<thead>"+
        "<tr role='row'>"+
          "<th class ='sorting_asc'>Numero de Historial</th>"+
          "<th class ='sorting_asc'>Nombre</th>"+
      "</thead>"+
    "<tbody>");
```

Y finalmente recorro los datos con un bucle para imprimir todos los resultados:

```
for(var i = 0; i < elementos.count; i++){

    $('#dataTables-example').append("<tr class='odd gradeA'>"+
        "<tr class='odd gradeA'>"+
          "<td>"+elementos.historias[i].nh+"</td>"+
          "<td>"+elementos.historias[i].name+"</td>"+
        "</tr>");
}
  $('</tr> ').append("</tbody>"+
      "</table>"+
    "</div>"+
    "<script src='vendor/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'></script>"+
    "<script src='vendor/datatables-plugins/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js'></script>"+
    "<script>"+
      "$(document).ready(function() {"+
        "$('#dataTables-example').DataTable({"+
          "responsive: true"+
        "});"+
      "});"
  );
```

El problema esta en que esto efectivamente, me muestra los resultados sin problemas, pero como una tabla normal, es decir, no se aplica el efecto de búsqueda y ordenación del plugin dataTables. En el ejemplo que viene en el plugin las siguientes lineas son las que ponen en marcha las características de la tabla:

```
<script src="../vendor/datatables-plugins/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendor/datatables-responsive/dataTables.responsive.js"></script>

<!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
<script src="../dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>

<!-- Page-Level Demo Scripts - Tables - Use for reference -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
        responsive: true
    });
});
</script>
```

Pero no sé dónde insertar ese fragmento para que funcione correctamente el plugin. Espero haberme explicado bien. Agradecería mucho una ayuda ya que me trae de cabeza.

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta radicando en la implementacion del plugin, actualmente estas inclustando con jquery la referencia al plugin cuando estas cargando los datos, si ya haz cargado esto arriba no es necesario incluirlo en la parte dinamica.

Imaginando que no tienes acceso al html para incluir el codigo referente a la tabla no puedes hacer referencia a un elemento que no existe en el DOM, en ese caso debes llamarlo de la siguiente forma.

```
$('#infoDonantes table').dataTable();
```

Si tienes acceso al html para establecer la estructura de la tabla y solo incrustar las nuevas rows te recomendaria hicieras esa separacion del codigo, sera de mejor lectura.

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada te hace falta cerrar un la etiqueta `<tr>` del `<thead>`

Tu problema esta en que estas concatenando los `scripts` de datatables de manera incorrecta, es decir:

En este fragmento, estas concatenando `html` al `DOM` pero no se realiza la llamada al los `scripts` del plugin, por lo tanto no tienes cargado el `script`

```
$('</tr> ').append("</tbody>"+
    "</table>"+
  "</div>"+
  "<script src='vendor/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'></script>"+
  "<script src='vendor/datatables-plugins/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js'></script>"+
  "<script>"+
    "$(document).ready(function() {"+
      "$('#dataTables-example').DataTable({"+
        "responsive: true"+
      "});"+
    "});"
);
```

Lo mejor es eliminar ese `.append()` y en el primero dejarlo de esta menra:

```
$('#infoDonantes').append("<div class='panel-body'>"+
  "<table width='100%' class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover' id='dataTables-example'>"+
    "<thead>"+
      "<tr role='row'>"+
        "<th class ='sorting_asc'>Numero de Historial</th>"+
        "<th class ='sorting_asc'>Nombre</th>"+
      "</tr>"+
    "</thead>"+
    "<tbody>"+
    "</tbody>"+
  "</table>"+
"</div>");
```

Primero es mejor dejar cargados los scripts en la pagina de esta manera:

```
<body>
<!-- Contenido de la pagina -->
...

<!-- script de la función de llenado de la tabla -->
...

<!-- Scripts cargados al inicio de la pagina -->
<script src="../vendor/datatables-plugins/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendor/datatables-responsive/dataTables.responsive.js"></script>
<!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
<script src="../dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>

<!-- Page-Level Demo Scripts - Tables - Use for reference -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
        responsive: true
    });
});
</script>
</body>
```

debido a que tu tabla no existe aun en el `DOM` este fragmento de código no te funcionara, para que funcione debes tener al menos las etiquetas `<table>` declaradas en el `DOM`

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
        responsive: true
    });
  });
</script>
```

O bien aplicar el plugin de manera dinámica de esta forma:

```
//funcion que se llama para cargar la información de la tabla
function cargarTabla(){
  //me imagino que aquí haces la peticion ajax para los datos
  //aquí concatenas la tabla a $('#infoDonantes')
  //llenando el cuerpo de la tabla
  for(var i = 0; i < elementos.count; i++){
    $('#infoDonantes').find('#dataTables-example').append(""+
       "<tr>"+
          "<td>"+elementos.historias[i].nh+"</td>"+
          "<td>"+elementos.historias[i].name+"</td>"+
       "</tr>");
  }

  $('#infoDonantes').find('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        //destruir tablas viejas y aplicar a esta nueva con este selector $('#infoDonantes')
        destry: true //esto es para evitar un error de duplicidad a una tabla
    });
}
```